# Create a multi-dimensional array with PHP from lineal array

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, tableofcontents

**TL;DR** I'm looking for a function to create a nested `<ol>` list from a one-dimensional array in PHP.

1) Currently I have this simplified markup in my test page:

```
<h2>Spiders</h2>
<h2>Beetles</h2>
<h3>External morphology</h3>
<h4>Head</h4>
<h4>Thorax</h4>
<h4>Legs</h4>
<h3>Anatomy and physiology</h3>
<h2>Ants</h2>
```

2) Which then is captured by a pretty simple function into an one-dimensional array like this:

```
array
(
    0 => "H2 Spiders",
    1 => "H2 Beetles",
    2 => "H3 External morphology",
    3 => "H4 Head",
    4 => "H4 Thorax",
    5 => "H4 Legs",
    6 => "H3 Anatomy and physiology"
    7 => "H2 Ants"
);
```

3) This is the tricky part, because I use the next loop with these overly complicated if statements to populate a multi-dimensional array.

```
$toc = array ();
//
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $value_arr = explode(' ', $value, 2);
    $depth = str_replace("H", "", $value_arr[0]);
    $content = $value_arr[1];
    //
    if ($depth == 1) $toc[$title] = null;
    elseif ($depth == 2) {
        if (empty (end ($toc))) $toc[array_key_last ($toc)] = array ($title => null);
        else $toc[array_key_last ($toc)][$title] = null;
    } elseif ($depth == 3) {
        if (empty (end ($toc[array_key_last ($toc)]))) $toc[array_key_last ($toc)][array_key_last ($toc[array_key_last ($toc)])] = array ($title => null);
        else $toc[array_key_last ($toc)][array_key_last ($toc[array_key_last ($toc)])][$title] = '';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array (
[Spiders] => 
[Beetles] => Array
    (
        [External morphology] => Array
            (
                [Head] => 
                [Thorax] => 
                [Legs] => 
            )
        [Anatomy and physiology] => 
    )
[Ants] => 
)
```

4) And finally be parsed with this function into an perfectly indented  html list.

```
function table_of_contents ($toc, $output = '') {
    foreach ($toc as $key => $value) {
        $output = "$output <li><a href='#@" . sanitize_title ($key) . "'>$key</a>" . (is_array ($value) ? table_of_contents ($value) : null) . '</li>';
    }
    //
    return "<ol>$output</ol>";
}
//
table_of_contents ($toc);
```

-

1. Spiders
2. Beetles

   1. External morphology

      1. Head
      2. Thorax
      3. Legs
   2. Anatomy and physiology
3. Ants

Everything works fine in the 1st, 2nd and 4th steps, but my current approach has the drawback that only allows me up to three levels of depth from the first array in the 3rd step.

My question is whether there is a more efficient and cleaner way to create the multi-dimensional array with (maybe) a recursive function or something like that?

Comment: @Saf Sorry, somehow I missed that part, I just get it from the heading tag in the first array; for example, <h2>Foo</h2> will become "H2 Foo" and $depth = '2' and $content = 'Foo'. I've already corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to parse your input using [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all); this can give you arrays of depths and associated values. You can then iterate through those arrays, opening an `<ol>` when the depth increases, and closing it when the depth decreases:

```
$html = '<h2>Spiders</h2>
<h2>Beetles</h2>
<h3>External morphology</h3>
<h4>Head</h4>
<h4>Thorax</h4>
<h4>Legs</h4>
<h3>Anatomy and physiology</h3>
<h2>Ants</h2>';

preg_match_all('/<h(\d)>([^<]+)/', $html, $matches);
$cdepth = $matches[1][0] - 1;
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $depth) {
    if ($depth > $cdepth) {
        echo "\n" . str_repeat(' ', $cdepth * 4) . "<ol>\n";
    }
    elseif ($depth < $cdepth) {
        echo "</li>\n" . str_repeat(' ', $depth * 4) . "</ol>\n" . str_repeat(' ', $depth * 4) . "</li>\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
    $cdepth = $depth;
    echo str_repeat(' ', $cdepth * 4) . "<li><a href=\"{$matches[2][$key]}\">{$matches[2][$key]}</a>";
}
while ($cdepth-- >= $matches[1][0]) {
    echo "</li>\n" . str_repeat(' ', $cdepth * 4) . "</ol>\n";
}
```

Output:

```html
<ol>
    <li><a href="Spiders">Spiders</a></li>
    <li><a href="Beetles">Beetles</a>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="External morphology">External morphology</a>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="Head">Head</a></li>
            <li><a href="Thorax">Thorax</a></li>
            <li><a href="Legs">Legs</a></li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Anatomy and physiology">Anatomy and physiology</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Ants">Ants</a></li>
</ol>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FkXXE)

**Update**

If you want the third stage array for other reasons than output, you can generate it with this recursive function (which still works from the output of `preg_match_all`):

```
$html = '<h2>Spiders</h2>
<h2>Beetles</h2>
<h3>External morphology</h3>
<h4>Head</h4>
<h4>Thorax</h4>
<h4>Legs</h4>
<h5>Feet</h5>
<h3>Anatomy and physiology</h3>
<h2>Ants</h2>';


function push_values(&$k, $depth, $content) {
    $output = array();
    $cdepth = $depth[$k];
    while ($k < count($depth)) {
        if ($depth[$k] == $cdepth) {
            $output[$content[$k]] = '';
            $k++;
        }
        elseif ($depth[$k] > $cdepth) {
            $output[$content[$k-1]] = push_values($k, $depth, $content);
        }
        else {
            return $output;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

preg_match_all('/<h(\d)>([^<]+)/', $html, $matches);
$key = 0;
print_r(push_values($key, $matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Spiders] => 
    [Beetles] => Array
        (
            [External morphology] => Array
                (
                    [Head] => 
                    [Thorax] => 
                    [Legs] => Array
                        (
                            [Feet] => 
                        )    
                )    
            [Anatomy and physiology] => 
        )    
    [Ants] => 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Ili7U)

Comment: @MauricioEsparza I've made an update to my answer to specifcally answer the third part of your question (generation of the multi-dimensional array) using a recursive function.

Comment: Tyvm for all your time and effort, I appreciate your help, this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Lastly, I would suggest a minor fix for the first code posted by @Nick causing an undesirable HTML output in the next scenario, where a depth difference greater than two will change the most superficial siblings; for example, the `<h3>` after `<h6>` become `<h5>` and the next `<h2>` was parsed as `<h4>`:

```
$html = '<h2>Spiders</h2>
<h2>Beetles</h2>
<h3>External morphology</h3>
<h4>Head</h4>
<h4>Thorax</h4>
<h4>Legs</h4>
<h5>Feet</h5>
<h6>Toes</h6>
<h3>Anatomy and physiology</h3>
<h2>Ants</h2>';

foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $depth) {
    if ($depth > $cdepth) {
        echo "\n" . str_repeat(' ', $cdepth * 4) . "<ol>\n";
    }
    elseif ($depth < $cdepth) {
        echo "</li>\n" . str_repeat(' ', $depth * 4) . "</ol>\n" . str_repeat(' ', $depth * 4) . "</li>\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
    $cdepth = $depth;
    echo str_repeat(' ', $cdepth * 4) . "<li><a href=\"{$matches[2][$key]}\">{$matches[2][$key]}</a>";
}
while ($cdepth-- >= $matches[1][0]) {
    echo "</li>\n" . str_repeat(' ', $cdepth * 4) . "</ol>\n";
}
```

Output:

```html
<ol>
    <li><a href="Spiders">Spiders</a></li>
    <li><a href="Beetles">Beetles</a>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="External morphology">External morphology</a>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="Head">Head</a></li>
            <li><a href="Thorax">Thorax</a></li>
            <li><a href="Legs">Legs</a>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="Feet">Feet</a>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="Toes">Toes</a></li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Anatomy and physiology">Anatomy and physiology</a></li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Ants">Ants</a></li>
</ol>
</li></ol></li></ol>
```

-

To address that I just added another *while* statement to put the correct amount of `</li></ol>` before adding the next `<li>` element, which now can correctly validate the W3C inspector.

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $depth) {
    if ($depth > $cdepth) {
        echo "\n" . str_repeat(' ', $cdepth * 4) . "<ol>\n";
    }
    elseif ($depth < $cdepth) {
        while ($cdepth -- > $depth) {
            echo "</li>\n" . str_repeat(' ', $depth * 4) . "</ol>\n" . str_repeat(' ', $depth * 4) . "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
    $cdepth = $depth;
    echo str_repeat(' ', $cdepth * 4) . "<li><a href=\"{$matches[2][$key]}\">{$matches[2][$key]}</a>";
}
while ($cdepth-- >= $matches[1][0]) {
    echo "</li>\n" . str_repeat(' ', $cdepth * 4) . "</ol>\n";
}
```

Output:

```html
<ol>
    <li><a href="Spiders">Spiders</a></li>
    <li><a href="Beetles">Beetles</a>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="External morphology">External morphology</a>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="Head">Head</a></li>
            <li><a href="Thorax">Thorax</a></li>
            <li><a href="Legs">Legs</a>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="Feet">Feet</a>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="Toes">Toes</a></li>
        </ol>
        
</li>
        </ol>
        
</li>
        </ol>
        
        <li><a href="Anatomy and physiology">Anatomy and physiology</a></li>
    </ol>
    
    <li><a href="Ants">Ants</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider that scenario. Your solution is good, or you could combine our two recursive functions - mine to make the array and yours to output the list - which get that scenario correct: https://3v4l.org/PUTCb